# Imgur blocks screenshot download

Tags: imgur

We use Flameshot as a screenshot software.

From time to time we received error with downloading images to imgur.

https://i.imgur.com/2Mu2RW5.png - here is error text

As I understand there is some limit for downloads from one IP? How to increase this limit?

Nothing. After 10-15 min it works fine.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)